# VBA- USERFORM using COMBO BOX and CommandButton

Tags: vba

I have a combobox & command button. Combo box has list say "No attachment" & "With Attachment", these are Outlook Templates. No matter which ever I select, the combobox always selects case as 0 which is "No attachment".

I've done everything but can't seems to figure out what is wrong. Below is the code I use for Userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "No Attachment"
    .AddItem "With Attachment"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    lstNum = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

And this is the code I put in Module:

```
Public lstNum As Long

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

    UserForm1.Show

    Select Case lstNum

    ' Following the listbox entries

    Case -1
    '  -1 is what you want to use if nothing is selected
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\test\No Attachment.oft")

    Case 0
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\test\No Attachment.oft")
    Case 1
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\test\With Attachment.oft")
    
    
    End Select

    ' Use for a specific purpose not randomly
    ' On Error Resume Next

    With outMail
        .To = "cell.Value"    ' For this Outlook demo

        .Display
    End With

    ' On Error GoTo 0

cleanup:
        Set outMail = Nothing

  End Sub
```

Comment: Hi.  Stack Overflow is working on a new feature [Your Reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction?cb=1).   If you have found your answer, please click on the ICON under voting.  Long-Life to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign public variables their values in a module not an object's code so instead of:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    lstNum = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

you would want:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Module1.assingLstNum ComboBox1.ListIndex 'or whatever module you want to use
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

In Module1:

```
Sub assignLstNum(indexval as Long)
    lstNum = indexval
End Sub
```

Comment: @yanger rai, see [this link](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) for why `Unload Me` and `UserForm1.Show` should be avoided too.